# Regex to find substrings of a string missing some parts

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long string (html of website) and I want to scrape the substrings.

For example, some of the output contains something like this:

```
<span title="Minecraft: Pocket Edition" class="oneline-info title-info">
  <a href="/apps/ios/app/minecraft-pocket-edition/">Minecraft: Pocket Edition</a>
</span>


    <span title="Mojang" class="oneline-info add-info" data-items="1">
        <a href="/apps/ios/publisher/mojang/">Mojang</a>
    </span>
```

I want to scrape everything from `<span title=` to `</span>` (In the above example, that means it will be 2 different matches)

So, I have this code:

```
        var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"<span title=(?<content>(?:(?!""</span>).)+)");
        scrapeTitles.AddRange(matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["content"].Value).ToList());
```

But for some reason, it's not scraping all the data between those 2 words. It only gives me outputs like this:

```
"Minecraft: Pocket Edition" class="oneline-info title-info">
"Mojang" class="oneline-info add-info" data-items="1">
"Clash of Clans" class="oneline-info title-info">
"Supercell" class="oneline-info add-info" data-items="1">
```

I need to scrape all the data, including the `<a>` line as well.

```
"Mojang" class="oneline-info add-info" data-items="1">
            <a href="/apps/ios/publisher/mojang/">Mojang</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your match doesn't take proper care of the new line character.

Try this one:

```
<span title=(?<content>(?:(.|\n)(?!</span>))+)
```

See [live version](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Cspan%20title%3D(%3F%3Ccontent%3E(%3F%3A(.%7C%5Cn)(%3F!%3C%2Fspan%3E))%2B)&i=%3Cspan%20title%3D%22Minecraft%3A%20Pocket%20Edition%22%20class%3D%22oneline-info%20title-info%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fapps%2Fios%2Fapp%2Fminecraft-pocket-edition%2F%22%3EMinecraft%3A%20Pocket%20Edition%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fspan%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cspan%20title%3D%22Mojang%22%20class%3D%22oneline-info%20add-info%22%20data-items%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fapps%2Fios%2Fpublisher%2Fmojang%2F%22%3EMojang%3C%2Fa%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fspan%3E).

Disclaimer: I stronly recommend ***NOT*** to do HTML (SGML actually) parsing using regular expressions. It leads to broken behavior in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You're not capturing line-breaks, so either update your regex to parse them, or do this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty), @"<span title=(?<content>(?:(?!""</span>).)+)");
```